# ASP.NET MVC project to push to a remote server

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET MVC project locally, but want to push to a remote server so that others can use that website. I have login access to the remote server.
Is this what i need to do?

1) add a folder to IIS in the remote server
2) copy my files to the folder on remote server. If so, which files should i copy?

Comment: There are lots of ways you could potentially do this. Use the Publish option in Visual Studio (which in itself can then choose from Web Deploy, File Share, FTP and other options as the publishing method), or build it and then manually copy the files to a server, or FTP them. Or you could use Azure build/release pipelines, or some other way using git. Lots of options. You need to do some research. But probably for a basic site and/or a beginner the Publish option in Visual Studio is the most likely route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a release publish profile, publish, grab the files from the directory it published to. This is the simplest way. You can automate this process if you have many releases. For example publishing directly to the server or checking code into a source control of some kind and having it publish to the server.

Comment: i only have one. so i publish to my local server, then copy to the remote server. add IIS there. right?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Visual Studio (not code) then right click on the project and select publish, then select the options to publish to a local folder. Copy all files in your published folder to your server.

If you're using ASP.NET Core then you can also navigate to the project folder and use the following command

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o PUBLISH_PATH_HERE
```

You will need to ensure that the server has your version of .NET runtime installed.

Comment: Since this question is tagged with ASP.NET rather than ASP.NET Core, it's perhaps worth noting that the `dotnet publish` command only works with .NET Core projects.

Comment: Thanks, I should point that out in my answer but I doubt the OP knows if they're using ASP.NET Core or not.